# Array of struct value is being changed when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have been working for some time on a programming project and am stuck on something that someone else may find trivial.

I have an array of struct, that stores values for an event node graph.

Everything works fine until the 85th loop where a enum value of "ACTIVE" is being assigned to a part of the array ( Q[0].state ) that is not even being called.

At this point Q[notifydep].state = QUEUED; should be happening (and does). notifydep = 2 at this loop.

The problem shows up in below code at first instance where it says Watch Point. (in the nested for loop)

Here is a part of the code where it is happening. I hope I am giving enough code and not too much...

```
for (int w = qstarted; w < qendrunning; w++) {
    PrintState(queue[w]);
    if (Q[queue[w]].completetime == 0 && Q[queue[w]].state == ACTIVE) {
        PrintState(queue[w]);
        jobscopy[queue[w]].finishTime = currentday + 1;
        Q[queue[w]].state = COMPLETED;
        PrintState(queue[w]);
        /*Put workers back into our available workers array*/
        for (int i = 0; i < jobscopy[queue[w]].numPeopleUsed; i++) {
            not_working_end++;
            not_working[not_working_end] = jobscopy[queue[w]].peopleIDs[i];
        }
        /*Notify dependent jobs that this job has completed*/
        for (int notify = 0; notify < Q[queue[w]].tocount; notify++) {
            notifydep = Q[queue[w]].to[notify]; // ancestor job#
            Q[notifydep].edges--; // decrement ancestor edge
            /*check if notified job has 0 edges, if 0 then enqueue job*/
            if (Q[notifydep].edges == 0 && Q[notifydep].state == WAITING) {
                queue[qend++] = Q[notifydep].jobnum; // add job to qend then increment qend 
                Q[notifydep].state = QUEUED;
                PrintState(notifydep);
                cout << "\n" << __LINE__ << "============== Watch Point ===============";
                PrintState(0);
            }
        }
        cout << "\n============== Watch Point ===============";
        PrintState(queue[w]);
        cout << "\n" << __LINE__ << "============== Watch Point ===============";
        PrintState(0);
        dequeue(queue, w); // remove completed job from job running queue                
        curjobs--;
    } else if (Q[queue[w]].completetime > 0 && Q[queue[w]].state == ACTIVE) {
        Q[queue[w]].completetime--;
    }
} // end check for completed jobs
```

This is the definition for the struct from my .h

```
struct AdjacencyList  {
      NodeType state; // what is present state of job? 
      NodePath path; // is job part of critical path?
      int jobnum;
      int edges;     
      int tocount;
      int fromcount;
      int completetime;
      int to[50];      
      int from[50]; 
  };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to c++ and have been learning a lot. I first spend a great deal of effort researching and debugging before bugging everyone on SO. Thanks

SUB

Comment: What are the sizes of the arrays? You don't write beyond the bounds of any of the arrays?

Comment: Your code would become a lot more readable, if you put `queue[w]` and `Q[queue[w]]` into local variables first thing in the loop.

Comment: What are Q, queue, and PrintState?

Comment: Also, some debuggers let you set breakpoints when the value at a certain address is modified. If you can, try using that (set &Q[0].state as the address to watch).

Comment: Oh, and have you tried running with memory-checking tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: Second what immibis said. In gdb, you could use the command `watch &Q[0]->state` and just run the program until you find what is causing the error.